# correct point to close a data reader in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in vb.net:

```
reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
If reader.HasRows Then
    While reader.read

    End While
End If
```

should i use reader.close after the `End While` or after the `End If`

Comment: I would rather say just dispose your `myCommand` after `End If` or use Using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use the [`Using`-statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) which ensures that unmanaged resources are disposed(even on error). This also closes the reader.

```
Using reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
   If reader.HasRows Then
      While reader.read

      End While
    End If 
End Using
```

[Is it necessary to manually close and dispose of SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744051/is-it-necessary-to-manually-close-and-dispose-of-sqldatareader)

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference where you put the `.Close`. It is more important to make sure you dispose of the command object (you should dispose of any object the implements `IDisposable`. From the code you posted it is not clear if you are doing this or not.

The easiest way to do this is to wrap it in a using block

If you look at the [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx). This is the pattern they use:

```
   Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        ' Call Read before accessing data.
        While reader.Read()

        End While

        ' Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close()
    End Using
```

But as the `SqlDataReader` also implements `IDisposable` - so it would good practise to also wrap the reader in a `using` block.

At the end of the `using` block, the `reader` is closed *and* disposed for you meaning you don't have to worry about it:

```
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()

            End While
        End Using

    End Using
```

Note that you don't need to check if `reader.HasRows` because the `reader.Read` will return False if there are no rows. See this answer for more details: [Should if call SqlDataReader.HasRows if I am calling SqlReader.Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196644/should-if-call-sqldatareader-hasrows-if-i-am-calling-sqlreader-read)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is

```
Try
    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        While reader.read

        End While
    End If
Catch ex as Exception
Finally
    reader.Close()
End Try
```