# Close SqlDataReader if there are no more rows left to read - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

This is causing me a headache. I know this question (or atleast variants of it) has been asked many times but before one flags it as a duplicate please consider the following code:

```
    string myConnectionString =  myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ToString();
     SqlConnection mySQLConnection;
     SqlCommand mySQLCommand;
     SqlDataReader mySQLDataReader;

    using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
       mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC", mySQLConnection);
       mySQLCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection;
       mySQLCommand.Connection.Open();
       using(mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader())
       {
         if (mySQLDataReader.HasRows)
         {
             if (mySQLConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
             {
                while (mySQLDataReader.Read())
                {
                  //Perform Logic : If the last record being returned meets some condition then call the below method
                   MethodCalled();
                }            
            }
         }
      }
         MessageBox.Show("Connection state: " + mySQLConnection.State);
   }
```

I would like to find a way to either:

1. Close the reader after it has finished reading
2. Break out of the `while-loop` when it has finished reading and there are no more rows left

But I just keep on getting a `SqlException` stating the following:

> invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed

Just from broad observation, I can trace that error is due to me returning data that contains one row only. The problem is that after it has read that row, the compiler goes back to `While(mySQLDataReader.Read()){}` and attempts to read through a table that does not contain any rows.

I attempted the following:

1. Wrapping the `ExecuteReader()` from the command object in a `using` block so that it automatically closes the reader and the connection respectively once it has done reading like so:

   ```
   using(mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader())
   {
       //Logic performed
   }
   ```
2. Just *before* the closing brace of the `while-loop`, I tried checking if there are any more rows left/returned from the sql command and breaking out the loop once that condition is satisfied:

   ```
   if(mySQLDataReader.HasRows == false) //No more rows left to read
   {
        break; //break out of loop
   }
   ```

Both attempts were unsuccessful. How can I get around this?

Comment: This would be strange. I have used it numerous times. The `Read()` function returns `false` at the end of data and doesn't throw exception. Can you post more code so we see what you're doing?

Comment: Could you post an minimal example highlighting your problem?

Comment: Could you, please, provide *more code*? It seems that you're trying to `Read` out of `using(...) {}` scope: `using(mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader()) {...} ... mySQLDataReader.Read()`;

Comment: Can you post the entire code block you are using that replicates this error?

Comment: What's the code you replaced with `//Logic performed`? It should be something like `while(mySQLDataReader.Read()) { /* do stuff with rows */  }`. The `Read()` method returns true while there are rows left to read, and false when you are reading the last row.

Comment: Wrap reader with `using..` is correct approach, unless you yielding return from inside of `using`

Comment: _"While(mySQLDataReader.Read()){} attempts to read through a dataset that does not contain any rows"_  This will consume the reader until there are no more rows, but why you use the term `DataSet`? Do you have one? Maybe it's just a misunderstanding. Show more code pleae.

Comment: Just for clarity, the issue is not only happening at debug time? And you are not expanding the reader variable in the debugger?

Comment: @Jerodev I have just posted the sample code that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be one of the following 3 things:

1. You're using `Read()` OUTSIDE the `using` block. Remember that `using` block will implicitly call `Close` and `Dispose` on your reader. Thus any `Read()` calls must be placed inside the `using` block.
2. The body of your `using` block is explicitly closing the reader. This seems improbable.
3. Apparently you have declared your `mySQLDataReader` at a higher level. It could be that some other (async) code is closing the reader. This also is unlikely. You shouldn't, in most cases, define a `DataReader` at global level.

### Edit

Reading the full code block that you have posted now, I'd suggest a few changes. Can you run the following and tell us if it runs:

```
using (var mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
   mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC", mySQLConnection, mySQLConnection);
   mySQLCommand.Connection.Open();
   using(mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (mySQLDataReader.Read())
      {
        //Perform Logic : If the last record being returned meets some condition then call the below method
         MethodCalled();
      }            
   }
}
```

If this version runs fine, we can then dig the problem better.

Comment: 2. I don't call `Dispose` nor `Close` anywhere within the while loop

Comment: 3. Yes I have declared the `DataReader` object globally and I have it used in my other functions without any problems so why would it be problematic now?

Comment: I added this before the closing brace of the `while-loop` and it worked as expected. You can update your answer after testing it. `if(mySQLDataReader.HasRows == false || mySQLDataReader.Read() == false)
 { 
      mySQLDataReader.Close();
      break;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

If there is no data to iterate, while loop will not execute at all. Do you need to check for HasRows as such? Also, you should use    CommandBehavior.CloseConnection when you are creating data reader. This will make sure that underlying connection is closed once you have read through it.

[Should if call SqlDataReader.HasRows if I am calling SqlReader.Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196644/should-if-call-sqldatareader-hasrows-if-i-am-calling-sqlreader-read)

[SQLDataReader Source Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs)

```
using (SqlConnection mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
using (SqlCommand mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC", mySQLConnection))
  {
    mySQLConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
     while (mySQLDataReader.Read())
       {
          //Code logic here
        }
        // this call to mySQLDataReader.Close(); will close the underlying connection
         mySQLDataReader.Close();
    }
     MessageBox.Show("Connection state: " + mySQLConnection.State);
}
```

Comment: So it does turn out that it is good practice to use `mySQLDataReader.HasRows)` hence I haven't omitted it from the question.

Comment: if you want to do something with it, inside the if condition.

Comment: I added this before the closing brace of the `while-loop` and it worked as expected. You can update your answer after testing it. `if(mySQLDataReader.HasRows == false || mySQLDataReader.Read() == false)
 { 
      mySQLDataReader.Close();
      break;
 }`

Comment: Read() enhances SqlDataReader cursor to next record, so, as such, when you have to actually do something with records, do not use it in if condition.